# Java calculate percentage based on items in array list

Tags: java, math, for-loop, arraylist

I was having some problem when trying to calculate the percentage based on an array list.

```
int total = 0;
    double percentage = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < accountList.size(); i++){
        total += Integer.parseInt(accountList.get(i).getTotalCount());
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < accountList.size(); j++){
        percentage = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(accountList.get(j).getTotalCount()) / (double)total);
        Log.i("PCT", String.valueOf(percentage));
    }
```

Basically the first loop is to calculate the total. Then as for second loop, I am looping each items in the array list divided by the total to get the percentage.

However, when I try to print out the percentage, I am getting 0.0. But then when I print out the total, it did returned me the total.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely all your fractions are less than 0.5 so when you round the faction you keep getting `0`.

I suspect you want to print the percentage which is 100 x the faction.

```
 long percentage = Math.round(100.0 * 
                Double.parseDouble(accountList.get(j).getTotalCount()) / total);
```

Or

```
 long percentage = 100L*Integer.parseInt(accountList.get(j).getTotalCount()) / total;
```

Using a integer result might not be ideal. I suggest adding a digit of precision like this.

```
 double percentage = 1000L 
                     * Integer.parseInt(accountList.get(j).getTotalCount()) 
                     / total / 10.0;
```

By multiplying by 10x what you need for the integer calculation, you get an extra digit of precision when you divide by 10.0.

e.g.

```
100 * 1 / 3 == 33
1000 * 1 / 3 / 10.0 == 33.3
```

Comment: So let's say I wanted it to be like 33. By using the *100, I also need to divide by 10 in the end?

Comment: @IWasSoLost You only need to x10 and /10.0 if you want to show one digit of precision, otherwise just use a `long` instead of a `double`

Answer (score 2):

`% = Value / Total * 100`

So the calculation should be :

```
percentage = Math.round((Double.parseDouble(accountList.get(j).getTotalCount()) * 100.0) / (double)total);
```